# .NET Google Auth / Identity / Scope

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-identity

I have a website that allows users to authenticate via Google. All is good and the users are happy. I have the following set up in my `Startup.cs` file.

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
  options.ClientId = "__CLIENTID__";
  options.ClientSecret = "__CLIENTSECRET__";
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.AccessType = "offline";
  options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent";
  options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("image", "picture");
});
```

One small part of my site allows existing users to connect to a separate Google account and access the Google Calendar associated with it.

I'm kicking off the auth flow for this in the usual way:

```
var redirectUrl = "...my redirect url";
var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);
return new ChallengeResult("Google", properties);
```

This is obviously problematic as I need to add a scope at this point in the flow:

```
options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
```

but I can't

Does anyone know a way around this?
Can I have another `.AddGoogle()` in my `Startup.cs` or maybe is there a way to manually write the auth flow (bypassing Identity) to get the access token and refresh token?

The main users of the app shouldn't have to permit access to their calendars when this is a very specific function for a minority of users.

Comment: signin is not oauth  They dont play well together.  I have never been able to get a refresh token back.   The offical sample for  [asp .net](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) with the google .net client library does not play well with the standard microsoft google signin, they clobber each other.   I have found the access token, but the refresh token i think is locked in the cookie some place that i have not been able to find.   I also want to link the user on the user table with a refresh token for a google api.

Comment: I tried asking on the github project [#2202](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2202) I have yet to find the refresh token.

Comment: well....that sucks 

Comment: it should be possible I just haven't had the time to work it out.   The entire system should be overloadable